# mypy AnyStr gives Incompatible types in assignment on trivial example

Tags: python, mypy

given the following class:

```
from typing import AnyStr

class A(object):

    def __init__(self, param):
        # type: (AnyStr) -> None
        self.a = param # type: AnyStr
```

I get the following output:

```
$ mypy . -v
LOG:  Mypy version 0.521
LOG:  Build finished in 1.199 seconds with 10 modules, 2076 types, and 2 errors
test.py:8: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "AnyStr")
test.py:8: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "bytes", variable has type "AnyStr"
```

How come this assign operation gives incompatible type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in mypy, but with a bit of detective work, I think I've figured this out.

### The Problem

This seems to work just fine if `AnyStr` is passed to a function, but fail when a variable is typed as `AnyStr`. For example, this seems to work fine:

```
from typing import AnyStr

def f(a):
    # type: (AnyStr) -> AnyStr
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f('cat'))
    print(f(b'dog'))
```

But this fails:

```
from typing import AnyStr

c = 3   # type: AnyStr
```

With the error:

```
mypy_anystr.py:3: error: Invalid type "typing.AnyStr"
```

This makes sense, because the idea of `AnyStr`, from [the documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#type-variables-with-value-restriction), is that it is intended to be *either* `str` or `bytes`, but it must be *consistent* within the scope of a given function call. The example they give for a `AnyStr` usage is:

```
def concat(a, b):
    #type: (AnyStr, AnyStr) -> AnyStr
    return a + b

concat('one', 'two')        # OK
concat(b'three', b'four')   # OK
concat('five', b'six')      # Error
```

Of course, unless `AnyStr` is global (and the example above shows that it is *not*), then assigning a variable outside of the scope of the original `AnyStr` variable (e.g. globally, or an attribute of a class) doesn't make sense, which is likely why it fails. I suspect the error message could be much more clear about this.

#### The Solution

Depending on what you actually want to accomplish, there are a few solutions here. If you are truly agnostic between `str` and `bytes`, then you can use `Union[Text, bytes]`:

from typing import Union, Text, AnyStr

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        #type: (AnyStr) -> None
        self.param = a  # type: Union[Text, bytes]
```

Note in this case I used `AnyStr` on the input, but in this case it's equivalent to `Union[Text, bytes]`, since there is only one parameter. Alternatively, if you actually *do* care about whether the parameter is a `str` or `bytes`, you can just take `AnyStr` and convert it to the version you want proactively:

```
from typing import Union, Text, AnyStr
from six import binary_type
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        #type: (AnyStr) -> None
        if isinstance(a, binary_type):
            b = a.decode()  # type: Text
        else:
            b = a

        self.param = b  # type: Text
```

Note that this can get funky if `a` is encoded in a weird locale or something, so be aware that this is a simplified example and YMMV if you try to actively decode `bytes` objects.